# PHP ffmeg - ffmpeg_animated_gif err

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have a code

```
$movie = new ffmpeg_movie($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/file.mp4'); 
$gif=new ffmpeg_animated_gif("gif_pre.gif",100 ,100 ,24); 

for ($frame = 150; $frame <= 200; $frame++) 
{
   $image = $movie->getFrame($frame);
   $gif->addFrame($image);
}
```

and error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ffmpeg_animated_gif' not found in {here were err line and path to file}
```

OS: Windows 7 | Denwer | FFMPEG: 0.6.0-svn

phpinfo:

```
mpeg-php version    0.6.0-svn 
ffmpeg-php built on     Sep 8 2010 12:13:47 
ffmpeg-php gd support   enabled 
ffmpeg libavcodec version   Lavc52.87.4 
ffmpeg libavformat version  Lavf52.78.3 
ffmpeg swscaler version     SwS0.11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg_animated_gif` was removed in version [0.6.0](http://ffmpeg-php.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ffmpeg-php/branches/ffmpeg-php/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ChangeLog?revision=610&view=markup#l12), **0.5.3.1** was the last one with this functionality.